# Writing buffer to file doesn't return error, so why is file empty afterwords?

Tags: go, buffer

I'm trying to read all standard input and write it to a file. It's writing nothing to the file provided. Why is it not working?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    fn := os.Args[1]
    var input bytes.Buffer
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, scanner.Text())
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, "\n")
    }   

    fi, _ := os.Open(fn)
    defer fi.Close()

    fi.Write(input.Bytes())
}
```

And then...

```
touch writetothis.txt
echo "input text" | go run main.go writetothis.txt
# writetothis.txt is empty
```

Comment: you aren't checking the error on line `fi, _ := os.Open(fn)` how do you know it even opens.. it could silently fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Open` opens a file in read-only mode.
Refer to documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open

Instead, use [`OpenFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile).

Also, always check for errors whenever you code. It'll save you at least weeks of work-hours in your lifetime.

Here is a working code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fn := os.Args[1]
    var input bytes.Buffer
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, scanner.Text())
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, "\n")
    }

    fmt.Println(input.Bytes())
    fi, err := os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0755)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error with Open()",err)
    }
    defer fi.Close()

    n, err := fi.Write(input.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error with Write()", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Bytes written to file: ",n)
}
```

Comment: `os.Create` would be simpler if the file is simply being written and the contents should be discarded if it already exists. If it's being read and written, or if it needs to opened for appending, then `os.OpenFile` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can silently fail because you aren't checking the error.  It's likely a path issue. You can change your code slightly and let `ioutil` handle file creation so that paths aren't so much of an issue. Remember to always check the errs

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fn := os.Args[1]
    var input bytes.Buffer
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, scanner.Text())
        fmt.Fprintf(&input, "\n")
    }

    err := ioutil.WriteFile(fn, input.Bytes(), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're correct that the errors should be checked, but the errors would merely be a symptom of the problem in this case. That said, the OP probably hasn't seen `ioutil.WriteFile` yet, so +1 for illustrating an alternative to `os.Create`/`os.OpenFile`.